# function for displaying a message to the user

Tags: php

I just came across a function that is used to display an error message to the user and there is a part of it that I don't understand.Here id the function.

```
public function display(){
    echo "<div class=\"flash " . $this->type . "\">". $this->$msg ."</div>";
}
```

Can someone please explain to me what the purpose of the `"\"` is here?

Comment: It's an `escape` character used before `"` to display text. Can also be replaced by `<div class='flash...` (apostrophe)

Comment: [The manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The \ is an escape character. It's used to make sure that the double quotes **"** inside the other double quotes get displayed. Another way to write it would be:

```
public function display(){
    echo '<div class="flash ' . $this->type . '">'. $this->$msg .'</div>';
}
```

I think the above is more readable. Whenever I need to actually output a double quote, I put it inside a single-quoted string. However, there are differences between single-quoted strings and double-quoted strings in PHP that you will want to read up on: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double

Answer (score -1):

As Fred said, it is an escape character, that allows you to put characters as quotation mark and such.